# setting the prototype of a function using object.create()

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I'm looking at at two examples from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) about inheritance and prototypes. There seems to be some conflict in my understanding given these two examples—they seem contradictory:

```
var a = {a: 1};
//inheritance looks like: a ---> Object.prototype ---> null
var b = Object.create(a);
//inheritance looks like: b ---> a ---> Object.prototype ---> null
console.log(b.a); // 1 (inherited)
```

Makes sense so far, but then on another page, learning about the .call() method:

```
function Product(name, price) {
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;

  if (price < 0) {
    throw RangeError('Cannot create product ' +
                      this.name + ' with a negative price');
  }

  return this;
}

function Food(name, price) {
  Product.call(this, name, price);
  this.category = 'food';
}

Food.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype);

function Toy(name, price) {
  Product.call(this, name, price);
  this.category = 'toy';
}

Toy.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype);

var cheese = new Food('feta', 5);
var fun = new Toy('robot', 40);
```

Isn't Food's prototype now going to be the Product's prototype? i.e Function.prototype?

I was expecting:

```
Food.prototype = Object.create(Product)
```

Does this have to do with the fact that it's a function?

Thanks,

Comment: "*i.e Function.prototype?*" The `prototype` property of a `function` is initially a plain `Object`. The property is used for inheritance rather than the `function` itself so the various types don't have to inherit `Function` behavior.

Comment: `Constructor.prototype` is the reference to the object which should be inherited by instances of `Constructor` whereas `obj.prototype` is just a regular property just like any other, for example, `a.prototype` and `b.prototype` in your code are both _undefined_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do seem to have a misunderstanding of the second example. In particular, I think you may have some confusion between "constructor" and "prototype". I'll try to explain by going through the example.

First of all, the example declares a function, `Product`. This is an ordinary function, but the fact that it references `this` suggests that it's intended to be used as a constructor. Note that the `return this` statement is superfluous, as a function's return value is ignored when invoked as a constructor (ie with `new`).

`Product` is itself an object - it's a function, and functions are objects. All objects have a prototype, which is different from what you get with `Product.prototype` - you can access it with `Object.getPrototypeOf(Product)`, and you'll find it to be equal to `Function.prototype`. All objects also have a contructor, which can be obtained with `Product.constructor`. Since product is a function, its constructor is `Function`. The constructor is always a function.

Then, what's the `prototype` attribute? Not all objects have this - only functions do. It's not the prototype of `Product` itself. It's the prototype of any objects created via `new Product(name,price)` (ie, Object.getPrototypeOf(new Product(name,price)) == Product.prototype). If you want to think of `Product` as a class, then the class's prototype is `Product.prototype`. And what's the constructor of `Product.prototype`? It's easy to confirm that `Product.prototype.constructor == Product`.

So, what would happen if you did `Food.prototype = Object.create(Product)`, instead of `Food.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype)`?

1. `Object.create(Product)' creates a new object and sets its prototype to`Product`. You can verify that`Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.create(Product)) == Product`.
2. Then you set `Food.prototype` to this new object.
3. Now, when you call `var cheese = new Food('feta', 5)`, you're invoking `Food` as a constructor. Thus, a new object is created, and `Food.prototype` is set as its prototype, ie the new object's prototype is an object whose prototype is `Product`.
4. Next, `Food` is called with this new object as its `this` argument. `Food` then passes the `this` argument on to `Product`. So far, so good, right?
5. Here's the catch. You'll find that `Food.constructor == Function`. Huh? What happened to `Product`? Well, your prototype chain reaches back to `Product`, sure, and the prototype of `Product` is `Function.prototype`, and nowhere along that chain was the constructor overridden.

So... in some weird way, it almost looks as though `cheese` is a function? Well, it's not (you can't call it, for example), but it won't inherit any attributes or methods you put in `Product.prototype` (though it will inherit ones put in `Product`). The bad thing is that it will also inherit any methods defined in `Function` - for example, the `call` method itself. Worse, trying to use this (eg `cheese.call({})`) will raise an error, since `cheese` is not itself a function.

Thus, the correct way is to use `Food.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype)` (or equivalently, `Food.prototype = new Product`).

---

The key point here is probably that `Product.prototype` is not the prototype of `Product`. Rather, it's the prototype of new objects created by invoking `new Product(...)`.

Comment: Really appreciate your answer; I think it clarified a lot—especially the bit about .prototype property having to do with how new objects are created using the function it belongs to. I do have a few questions, though:
In 5), when you say that the prototype of `product` is `Function`, did you mean to say it's `Function.prototype`? also, since `Product.prototype` is empty, what good does it do? Would the chain now look like:
`Food ---> Product.prototype ---> Object.prototype ---> null?`

Comment: Yes, the prototype of `Product` is `Function.prototype`. The prototype of `Food.prototype` is `Product.prototype`, which is empty in the example; however, adding something to `Product.prototype` makes it appear in `Food.prototype` as well, even if it's added much later.

Comment: One more thing: I was recursively calling Object.getPrototypeOf to see what the chain looked like. I was surprised that I had to call it a total of 4 times to reach `null`. Why is that? I thought the chain would look like:
cheese ---> {} ---> Object.prototype ---> null
That's only 3, what's the missing link in the chain? When I use safari, I see `Product` show up as the prototype of cheese. Is it because it's the constructor of Product.prototype?

Comment: Regarding the first question, the chain is cheese --> Food.prototype --> Product.prototype --> Object.prototype --> null. Regarding the second, I think that's just an artifact of how Safari prints objects, by using the constructor name as if it were a class name. If you add a line `Food.prototype.contructor = Food`, Safari will print `Food` when you ask for `Object.getPrototypeOf(cheese)`. It's actually printing `Food.prototype`, which you can verify by adding some data members to `Food.prototype` and clicking the disclosure triangle beside the result of `Object.getPrototypeOf(cheese)`.

Answer (score 0):

Either way works. Two different objects can have the same prototype. You can set one prototype, say `Foo.prototype`, to be the same object as `Bar.prototype`. So you can set it to either the prototype of an object, or an instance of the object. You can do either one.

The difference is, sometimes you want to have one object, Foo, inherit methods from another object, Bar, so you make the Foo.prototype equal to Bar.prototype. So every method on the prototype of Bar are now available as methods on Foo. But let's you want methods to be added to Bar's prototype but not to Foo's. In that case, you could do what you suggested, and make Bar's prototype an instance of the Foo object instead of it's prototype. That way, when you add method's to Bar's prototype, you're just adding it to that one instance of Foo, instead of the Foo prototype which affects ALL Foo instances.